# FocusListener for all controls of a Composite

Tags: java, focus, swt

I've written code for a `Composite` containing multiple controls (`StyledText`s, `Button`s, etc.).

I wanted to implement a `FocusListener` for the whole `Composite` (not only for one of the controls inside of it), but the FocusListener did not do anything.

---

I tried to implement it myself, and my attempt was: Add a `FocusListener` to every Control inside the composite and handle these events.

While trying to do so, I found some problems:

- When two controls have a FocusListener and I change the focus from one to the other, the `FocusLost` event is fired before the `FocusGained`
- So I can't find out if the focus was given to one of the other controls in my composite, or if the composite lost the focus completely.

**Note:** I tried using `Display.getFocusControl()` inside the `focusLost(...)` method, but it only returns the control from which the focus is taken!

---

**My question**: Is it possible to find out which control will receive the focus next while being inside the `focusLost(...)` method?

If not: Is there any other way to implement a `FocusListener` for a `Composite`?

Comment: What is it that you want to achieve in the first place?

Comment: @Baz i'm writing a TextEditorControl which is embedded in a bigger GUI. Everytime the user clicks on something else than this control (the textfield or the font buttons) the text shall be saved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time the `focusLost()` event is sent, it isn't yet known which control (if any) will receive the focus.

You can add a *display filter* that will inform you whenever a control within your entire application gains focus. Within your ' Listener` implementation, you can save the text input whenever a control gains focus that is not contained in the composite. For example:

```
Listener listener = new Listener() {
  @Override
  public void handleEvent( Event event ) {
    if( event.widget != text || event.widget != fontButton || ... ) {
      save();
    }
  }
};
display.addFilter( SWT.FocusIn, listener );
```

Make sure to add the listener only while the observed composite is alive. Remove the filter when the composite is disposed of.

```
display.removeFilter( SWT.FocusIn, listener );
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `SWT.FocusIn` as you want to know when a widget that isn't one from the target composite gains focus?

Comment: @Baz Sure, you are right. I've edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann this is a great idea, thanks a lot. I have also found another way to do it (by listening for `SWT.Deactivate` and `SWT.Deactivate` events)

Comment: This is indeed a god solution. Glad that you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

@RüdigerHermanns works pretty good, but for the sake of completeness I'll post my solution here too:

I've written listeners for `SWT.Activate` and `SWT.Deactivate` in my composite:

```
public MyComposite(Composite parent, int style)
{
    super(parent, style);
    createGuiElements(this);

    this.addListener(SWT.Deactivate, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event)
        {
            for (FocusListener listener : focusListeners) listener.focusLost(new FocusEvent(event));
        }
    });
    this.addListener(SWT.Activate, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event)
        {
            for (FocusListener listener : focusListeners) listener.focusGained(new FocusEvent(event));
        }
    });
}
```

which notify all focusListeners on the `Composite`.